# Conditional/Absolute Convergance

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-2)^n$ converges conditionally at $x=-1$ and diverges at $x=7$. Which of the following could be true?

A) The series converges absolutely at $x=5$.

B) The series diverges at $x=3$.

C) The series diverges at $x=0$.

D) The series converges absolutely at $x=-2$.

We can eliminate choices B and C right away. But both A and D are also impossible. Is there a correct answer anyway?

Comment: This is similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772222/1119495

Comment: @MissMae Thank you for your comment. I have seen that question. Unfortunately, it discusses only convergence not absolute vs conditional.

Comment: Why do you think A is impossible?

Comment: @AndreasBlass because if for x=-1 the series converges conditionally, then it means the series with absolute value terms diverges. But for x=5 you get the same thing if you consider it's absolute value terms. I hope I could explain.